# Eclipse Maven Export Missing

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I'm using [Eclipse Kepler 64 bit](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/SR2-with-Java8-patches/eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-Java8-win32-x86_64.zip). It already has m2e (maven plugin) pre-installed by default.

The import wizard has a Maven option but the export one doesn't:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEG5B.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/38G5K.png]

I tried installing m2e from the Marketplace but it said that there was nothing to install.

How do I get it as export option as well?

Comment: What kind of export? M2E is a Plugin for Eclipse which supports working with Maven projects within Eclipse. Outside of Eclipse you can simply use the command line for Maven project `mvn clean package`. What do you expect to export from Eclipse?

Comment: "Export" to do what with maven? The closest is the "install or deploy an artefact in a Maven Repository", which is already in the Import/Maven menu.

Comment: I expect an export option for maven projects just like there is one for imports.

Comment: Sorry I did't get it: What should be the result of this "export option"?

Comment: When importing, dependencies are downloaded and linked so that the project can compile. When exporting it should exclude the downloaded libraries since the pom.xml already specifies them. That should be the point of using maven I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the [M2E plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_FAQ) is concerned, using [Maven with Eclipse](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html) involve importing existing project, and making sure the `pom.xml` is complete (with the right "nature" added in it, in order to generate the right `.project`, as in [this example](http://vikashazrati.wordpress.com/2007/12/22/adding-project-nature-to-your-maven-pomxml/))
See "[Importing Maven Projects](http://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/creating-sect-importing-projects.html)" in the [Sonatype book](http://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/index.html).

But once the project is imported, it becomes a regular project (with additional maven capabilities), without any maven-specific export options.

All you need to "export" a maven project are the sources and the `pom.xml`: anyone can then run maven to get all the dependencies (from the `pom.xml` specifications).

Comment: So I can't import a project using maven, edit it and export it without the downloaded libraries again using Eclipse? Sure, it can be done by hand but there should be a convenient export solution.

Comment: Normally the things coming out of your maven project are (1) your jar files, which are in /target folder and you can get maven to export/deploy to nexus for you.  (2) your source files, which should be kept in source control, like svn or git.

Comment: @user3764804 yes, maven is based on a declarative approach: you declare what you need in the `pom.xml`. If the "export" includes the `pom`, you can then reproduce the build at will.